# s3 bucket not created for AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

ideally when we create an elastic beanstalk application , it should be creating a corresponding s3 bucket. so that uploading works fine. 
But i created a EB application and no correspoding s3 bucket is not created.
Any reasons?

Comment: Make sure you're in the correct region - I've found that the console likes to switch to "US West (Oregon)" even though all of my resources live in US East. Look in the upper-right corner for the region dropdown.

Comment: But S3 doesnt have any region..so can that affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like EB doesnt create a new bucket for every EB environment. It uses one of the existing buckets for existing EB. I created a new EB for testing and in the initial logs , its printed its using the existing bucket.